# How do I delcare a dependancy with artifactory

Tags: java, gradle, dependency-management, artifactory

I'm new to artifactory and have just uploaded a bunch of custom jars to one of my repos. I now want to declare what dependencies there are between these jars so that when using gradle and specifying A.jar as a dependency it will transitively resolve B.jar as a dependency of A.jar but I cant find anywhere to say that A.jar depends on B.jar.

Please help
TIA

Answer (score 1):

To get transitive dependency resolution, you'll have to upload a dependency descriptor (POM for a Maven repository, `ivy.xml` for an Ivy repository) for each Jar.

When you manually upload a Jar, Artifactory offers to generate a basic descriptor, which you can edit to fill in the dependency information.

When you build and publish a Jar with Gradle, Gradle will automatically generate and upload a descriptor containing dependency information according to the dependencies specified in the build script. If necessary, the generated descriptor can be further customized in the build script. See "8.6. Publishing artifacts" in the [Gradle User Guide](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html).